# Adding zoom property to chartOptions doesn't add any zoom feature

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I have a simple [timeline chart](https://apexcharts.com/vue-chart-demos/timeline-charts/multiple-series-group-rows/) built with `vue-apexcharts` (v.1.6.0).

As instructed by [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/zoom/) I added zoom property to `chartOptions.chart`:

```
chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'rangeBar',
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'x',
            resetIcon: {
              offsetX: -10,
              offsetY: 0,
              fillColor: '#fff',
              strokeColor: '#37474F'
            },
            selection: {
              background: '#90CAF9',
              border: '#0D47A1'
            }
          }
        },
```

but it **didn't add any zoom feature** to the chart. The only additional features I have is `Download SVG` & `Download PNG`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since version 3.23.0, zoom works with the `rangeBar` charts too. Please update to the latest ApexCharts version and it will work.

Checkout the [demo](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/basic/)
[image]

Comment: I just tried this with 3.23.0, and I don't see it working. The demo link you provided doesn't actually demo zoom with bar charts. Did you mean to provide a different link?

Comment: Not with bar charts. It should work with rangeBar charts (timelines). I have added a screenshot in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** @junedchhipa just added support for zoomable `rangeBar` charts in v3.23.0 ([updated demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-on-line-charts-in-apexcharts-forked-efo8r?file=/src/App.vue))

---

In v3.22.x, the `zoom` option is not compatible with bar charts. You'll see it work for line charts:

```js
chartOptions: {
  chart: {
    // type: 'rangeBar', // ❌ zoom does not work with bar charts
    type: 'line',        // ✅ ok
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zoom-on-line-charts-in-apexcharts-6ysyz?file=/src/App.vue:466-523)